# Determine outer div's width by selected inner div

Tags: css

I have a html segment that looks like the following:

```
<div class="outer" style="min-width: 150px;">
   <div class="inner1">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span> // Can be very long, truncate as needed
   <div class="inner2"/>
</div>
```

The outer div has a minimal width, and can/will grow. What I want is so that the outer div's width grow as inner2 grows, but not for inner1. In other words, I want the outer div's width to be determined by inner2, as if inner1 doesn't exist, then add inner1 and let the width remain unchanged, e.g.

If inner2's width is less than 150px, then inner1's width will be 150px.

If inner2's width is more than 150px, then inner1's width will be the same as inner2's div.

Comment: The last sentence is missing the exact element identifier. "inner's" is not an element the code you provided. Can you identify the exact elements being discussed in the specification so that you get the answer that meets your expectations?

Comment: from @BradHurlbert, "The last sentence is missing the exact element identifier. "inner's" is not an element the code you provided. Can you identify the exact elements being discussed in the specification so that you get the answer that meets your expectations?"

Comment: @GibralterTop corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to accomplish your goal.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $outer = $('.outer');
    var $inner1 = $('.inner1');
    var $inner2 = $('.inner2');
    
       
    if ($inner2.width() > 150) {
       $inner1.css('width', $inner2.width()+'px');
       $outer.css('width', $inner2.width()+'px');
    }
  else
    {
      $outer.css('width', '150px');
    }
});
```

```css
.outer  {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.inner1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
.inner2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" style="min-width: 150px;">
   <div class="inner1">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span> // Can be very long, truncate as needed
  </div>
   <br />
  <div class="inner2">
  sadasda
</div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you to achieve your goal :)